# VB 2010 Database Error Return ID

Tags: database, vb.net, crash, return

I have vb 2010 database program with columns: ID, which is AutoNumber and i dont set value for it; Date - String; Amount - Number and Note - String. Sometimes, when i try to save new record, the program crash and send me to this code (in designer):

```
<Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(),  _
Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")>  _
Public Property ID() As Integer
Get
Return CType(Me(Me.tableWithdraws.IDColumn),Integer)
End Get
Set
Me(Me.tableWithdraws.IDColumn) = value
End Set
End Property
```

The crash is on the line:

```
Return CType(Me(Me.tableWithdraws.IDColumn),Integer)
```

What should i do?

Comment: And what is the error messsage? It is an important information to understand what happens here.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.RowNotInTableException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: This row has been removed from a table and does not have any data.  BeginEdit() will allow creation of new data in this row.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is not when you're saving the data, but instead when you're trying to retrieve it.  You need to test whether the row you're querying actually exists before you try to retrieve data from it and/or use a try-catch framework so that your program doesn't crash if the row you're querying doesn't exist.  Of course, you may also want to explore WHY the row you're querying doesn't exist.